# Whitelisting Google Recaptcha

Tags: google, whitelist, content-filter, webfilter

Barracuda Web Filter blocking the Google Recaptcha on one of our vendors sites.

We have tested with an unfiltered user to verify that it's the webfilter blocking

Searched for what to whitelist, the closest I got was a google groups post in *2015* listing these sites, but this information seems to be out of date as it's still not working with these unblocked

- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/
- https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/
- https://apis.google.com/

What is the currently recommended best practice for whitelisting Google's Recaptcha in a Web Filter?

== Updates Below ==
There seems to also be an oddity with the barracuda web filter where user level content filters seem to override domain level whitelists which is complicating my testing

Here's the current list of domains I'm trying, I'll update as we progress.

- pki.goog
- gstatic.com
- googleapis.com
- apis.google.com
- www.google.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We solved this using a different approach, specifically he got approval to be on more relaxed content filter settings.

If you get this working through domain whitelisting feel free to post for others

Comment: We did also add those 5 domains I listed to the whitelist under Block/Accept > Custom Categories